# SQL Statement that never returns same row twice?

Tags: sql

**Requirements**: I have a table of several thousand questions. Users can view these multiple choice questions and then answer them. Once a question is answered, it should not be shown to the same user again even if he logs in after a while.

**Question**

How would I go about doing this efficiently? Would [Bloom Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a **QuestionsAnswered** table and join on it in your select.  When the user answers a question, insert the question ID and the user ID into the table.

```
CREATE TABLE QuestionsAnswered (UserID INT, QuestionID INT)

SELECT *
FROM Question
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT QuestionID 
                 FROM QuestionsAnswered
                 WHERE UserID = @UserID)

INSERT INTO QuestionsAnswered
(UserID, QuestionID)
VALUES
(@UserID, @QuestionID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you add something to the users info in the database which contains a list of answered questions?

So when that user comes back you can only show them questions which are NOT answered?

Comment: That really isn't possible. Suppose he answers several hundred questions?

And how would one go about doing that in SQL? A giant NOT IN clause?

Comment: You could set bits for each question to save space (if the questions don't change).

Comment: You can't set bits on the questions because that would hide them from other users.

Well I know you can store XML in sql now right?  you gather the entire list of questions they have anwered.

you run a sproc, which creates a temp table off the "QuestionAnswered" table, and do a join.

Not sure how fast that would be, but I can't imagine it being that slow.

Comment: @BycullaB Time to finally open that SQL book perhaps?

Comment: Actually, why not create a Table... wait just read the answer below.  there ya go

Comment: Sorry people. I dont know why that didnt occur to me

Answer (score 1):

Create a many-to-many table between users and questions (userQuestions) to store the questions that have been answered already.  Then you'd only display questions that don't exist in that userQuestions table for that user.

Comment: I was just writing a comment above to suggest this exact thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You insert each question shown into a log table with question_id/user_id, then show him the ones that don't match:

```
SELECT [TOP 1] ...
  FROM questions 
  WHERE question_id NOT IN (
   SELECT question_id
   FROM question_user_log
   WHERE userd_id = <current_user>)
[ORDER BY ...]
```

or

```
SELECT [TOP 1] ...
   FROM questions AS q
   LEFT OUTER JOIN question_user_log AS l ON q.question_id = l.question_id
     AND l.user_id = <current_user>
   WHERE l.question_id IS NULL
[ORDER BY...]
```

after you show the question, you

```
INSERT INTO question_user_log (question_id, user_id) 
  VALUES (<question shown>, <current_user>);
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you cannot create a table to track questions shown then you can query the questions in a deterministic order (ie. by Id or by Title) and select each time the one with the rank higher than the last rank shown (using ROW_NUMBER() in SQL Server/Oracle/DB2, or LIMIT in MySQL). You'd track the last rank shown somewhere in your user state (you do have a user state, otherwise the whole question is pointless).